# How to use paper js to realize hollowed-out style

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

I want realize some hollowed-out style.

> just like this

[image: hollowed-out style]
And I use **canvas** to realize this style, but I don't know how to use **paper Js** to get same style.

In canvas, there are tow ways to draw path, clockwaise and anticlockwise, if u use anticlockwise, it will ignore fill color.
So I use the anticlockwise draw path to realize hollowed-style,

```
# use canvas
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#myCanvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  const pointsOutSide = [{
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
  }, {
    x: 400,
    y: 100,
  },{
    x: 400,
    y: 400,
  },{
    x: 100,
    y: 400,
  }]

  const pointsIntSideRevers = [{
    x: 300,
    y: 200,
  }, {
    x: 200,
    y: 200,
  }, {
    x: 200,
    y: 300,
  }, {
    x: 300,
    y: 300,
  }]

  for(let i = 0; i < pointsOutSide.length; i++) {
    const { x, y } = pointsOutSide[i];

    if(i === 0) {
      ctx.moveTo(x, y);
      continue;
    }

    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  }
  ctx.closePath();

  for(let i = 0; i < pointsIntSideRevers.length; i++) {
    const { x, y } = pointsIntSideRevers[i];

    if(i === 0) {
      ctx.moveTo(x, y);
      continue;
    }

    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)';
  ctx.fill();
```

But when I use the same way by paper js, it's not working, And I check source code of paper js, it use native canvas API. I don't know why they are different.

> This is paper Js version . Actually, it's not I want

[image: paper-js-version]

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown how you have set up the two rectangles in paperjs. I assume you have used a ["CompoundPath"](http://paperjs.org/reference/compoundpath/#compoundpath-object). When you create a compound path all subpaths usually have the same orientation (clockwise). You can call [path.reorient()](http://paperjs.org/reference/compoundpath/#reorient) to change the orientation of any nested overlapping paths.

Another method is use [subtract](http://paperjs.org/reference/compoundpath/#subtract-path) boolean operation. If the boundaries of paths don't "cross" each other, they will produce the same results.

[Here is a demo of different approaches.](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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)

Comment: Thanks! You absolutely solved my problem!